# Play,Pause,Resume & Hide in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my page I have Play,Pause,Resume & Stop Icons. When I click on Play icon Pause & Stop icons are shown similarly I want to show the Resume & Stop icon when I click on Pause icon.This is my code,please anyone help me out. Thank you

> HTML Code.

```
 <div id="checkDiv">
        <span mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="CheckIn">
        <md-icon svgIcon="play" style="color: #efefef;cursor: pointer;height: 15px;width: 15px;" (click)='openPause()' [hidden]='playDiv'></md-icon>
        </span>
        <span mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="pause">
        <md-icon svgIcon="pause" style="color: #efefef;cursor: pointer;height: 15px;width: 15px;"  *ngIf="playDiv" (click)='openPlay()' > </md-icon>
        </span>
        <span mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="resume">
         <md-icon svgIcon="play" style="color: #efefef;cursor: pointer;height: 15px;width: 15px;"  *ngIf="playDiv"  [hidden]='playDiv' (click)='openPause()' ></md-icon>
        </span>
        <span mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="CheckOut">
         <md-icon svgIcon="stop" style="color: #efefef;cursor: pointer;height: 15px;width: 15px;" *ngIf="playDiv" (click)='openPlay()'></md-icon>
        </span>
```

> Typescript

```
    public playDiv:boolean = false;
openPause() {
  this.playDiv = true;
}

openPlay() {
  this.playDiv = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set separate variables for the different buttons instead of having them all rely on playDiv. Create new boolean variables called resumeDiv and stopDiv, and pauseDiv. Set the *ngIf on each respective div to these new variables. Then, alter the openPause() and openPlay() to set the ones you want shown to true and the ones you want hidden to false.